# Getting marker "details" in gmaps.js

Tags: google-maps

I am using gmaps.js and I have the following when creating markers:

```
map.addMarker({
   lat: {{ $coord -> latitude }},
   lng: {{ $coord -> longitude }},
   icon: "{{ asset('img/red_dot.png') }}",
   draggable: true,
   infoWindow: {
      content: info
   },
   details: {
      id: {{ $coord -> id }}
   },
   dragend: function(e) {
      var lat = e.latLng.lat();
      var lng = e.latLng.lng();

      console.log(e);
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(lng);
    },
});
```

Everything is working smashingly, the dragend, the marker itself, etc. What I'm having an issue with is trying to get the marker details in the dragend event, namely getting the "id" that was set in the details block.

I can get the lat and lng and the event information just fine...but how do I pass in the marker's details to that event?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Simple answers are sometimes the hardest to get :)

Simply using "this" in the dragend gave me the full detailed information on the marker itself. For example:

```
dragend: function(e) {
   var lat = e.latLng.lat();
   var lng = e.latLng.lng();

   console.log(this);
   console.log(lat);
   console.log(lng);
 },
```